# Comparing two dataframes by column and add value from one to another in R

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I have a problem with my for loop in R where I try to compare two dataframes. In dataframe 1, there is a rating per participant per picture (cols = Participant, rows = Pic-ID). Then, I have a list of 155 dataframes. Each dataframe has a column with the Pic-IDs used in this run. I now want to add the ratings from dataframe 1 to the respective picture ID in each dataframe of the list. The for-loop looks like this:

```
for (t in 1:155) {
  for (j in sort(rep(1:31, 5))) {
    list_of_df[[t]]$rating <- df1[list_of_df[[t]]$picture_ID, j]
  }
}
```

The "t" variable loops through all 155 dataframes in the list. Since I have 5 dataframes per participant (which I should not combine into one), the "j" variable only increases after 5 loops, to ensure that the ratings from the correct participant are used.

There is no error when I start the loop, but when I compare the ratings of dataframe 1 and the added ones to each on in the list, they do not match up.

Sample data would be as followed:

```
df1 <- data.frame(picID = c("pic1", "pic2", "pic3", "pic4", "pic5", "pic6"),
                  sub1 = c(6, 15, 87, 4, 22, 56),
                  sub2 = c(77, 41, 3, 54, 28, 43))
rownames(df1) <- df1$picID
df1$picID <- NULL

sub1_1 <- data.frame(picID = c("pic3", "pic4"))
sub1_1 <- cbind(sub1_1, "rating" = NA)
sub1_2 <- data.frame(picID = c("pic6", "pic1"))
sub1_2 <- cbind(sub1_2, "rating" = NA)
sub1_3 <- data.frame(picID = c("pic2", "pic5"))
sub1_3 <- cbind(sub1_3, "rating" = NA)

sub2_1 <- data.frame(picID = c("pic2", "pic1"))
sub2_1 <- cbind(sub2_1, "rating" = NA)
sub2_2 <- data.frame(picID = c("pic4", "pic6"))
sub2_2 <- cbind(sub2_2, "rating" = NA)
sub2_3 <- data.frame(picID = c("pic5", "pic3"))
sub2_3 <- cbind(sub2_3, "rating" = NA)

list_of_df <- list(sub1_1, sub1_2, sub1_3, sub2_1, sub2_2, sub2_3)

for (t in 1:6) {
  for (j in sort(rep(1:2, 3))) {
    list_of_df[[t]]$rating <- df1[list_of_df[[t]]$picID, j]
  }
}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: If you want to compare data frames, it's much more efficient to use something like ``data.table::fintersect`` - could you providde a reproducible example of your data?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. How would that work with the sample code?